# 'Azure cognitive Search' - 'Fields' configuration issue

Tags: python, azure, azure-cognitive-services, azure-cognitive-search

I'm working on building a semantic search engine using 'Azure Cognitive Search'. I uploaded my excel dataset programmatically using python.

To search & run the queries, each field/column in the excel dataset can be associated with features like 'searchable', 'sortable', 'retrievable', 'filterable', & 'facetable'.

I tried selecting these features for the fields/columns in my dataset, but they are disabled somehow. Only the 'retrievable' option is selectable. I tried both programmatically & manually. Neither of these methods work.

[image: Azure 'Fields' checkboxes]

NOTE: I'm using a free trial version. Not sure if this is causing the issue, but the documentation says, "retrievable" has no effect on index size.
"filterable", "sortable", "facetable" consume more storage". Also, my data is very small with 8 rows & 10 columns, with mostly numbers & single-worded text.

My python code to select the features:

```
import pandas as pd
import json
from azure.search.documents.indexes.models import SimpleField, SearchFieldDataType
import os
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.search.documents.indexes import SearchIndexClient 
from azure.search.documents import SearchClient

df_azure=pd.read_excel("C:/stats.xlsx")

endpoint="https://azure-service.search.windows.net"
key="q5EMEa0at5VJRvwTVlkqWhvHSKs"

SearchIndexClient=SearchIndexClient(endpoint, AzureKeyCredential(key))
indexName="indexes-azure"

from azure.search.documents.indexes.models import (
    ComplexField,
    CorsOptions,
    SearchIndex,
    ScoringProfile,
    SearchFieldDataType,
    SimpleField,
    SearchableField
)

fields=[
     SearchableField(name="rule_name", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True),
     SearchableField(name="rule_description", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True),
     SearchableField(name="Date_of_execution", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True),
     SearchableField(name="Data_Source", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True),  
     SearchableField(name="Total_no_of_records", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True),
     SearchableField(name="No_of_failed_records", type=SearchFieldDataType.String, facetable=True, filterable=True, sortable=True)
    
] 
  
indexConfig= SearchIndex(name=indexName,
                         fields=fields,
                         scoring_profiles=[],
                         cors_options= CorsOptions(allowed_origins=["*"], max_age_in_seconds=60))


index=SearchIndexClient.create_index(indexConfig)


SearchClient = SearchClient(endpoint, indexName, AzureKeyCredential(key))
result = SearchClient.upload_documents(documents=DOCUMENTS)
print("DOCUMENT upload successful: {}".format(result[0].succeeded))


Output: DOCUMENT upload successful: True
```

Comment: Are you saying that you are not able to change the attributes like `Filterable` etc. on an existing index? If that's the case, then it is by design. For existing fields, these attributes cannot be changed. You can only set these attributes at the time of index creation.

Comment: This isn't very clear to me. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: What I meant was the behavior you’re seeing on portal (checkboxes being disabled) is correct behavior because you can’t change these values on existing fields on an index. These can only be set when you’re creating an index or adding a new field on an existing index. Hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can enable all the features including filtrable, search and faceable while creating a new index.

The index is successfully created with the provided code in both `standard` and `free-tier` resource with all the required features enable.

[image]

For the existing index you can make change for retrievable field and all the fields while adding new field.

For more details you can check this [documentation.](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/search/search-get-started-portal.md)